# list all entries and count occurrences in other table

Tags: sqlite

I have DB with few tables, 2 of which are defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [projects] (
  [id]  INTEGER         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [code]    VARCHAR(128)    UNIQUE NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
  [name]    VARCHAR(128)    DEFAULT "Not Set" NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
)

CREATE TABLE [tasks] (
  [id]          INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [project_id]  INTEGER  NOT NULL,
  [notes]       VARCHAR(512) DEFAULT 'Not Set' NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
  [start]       DATE  NOT NULL,
  [finish]      DATE  NOT NULL,
  [rate_id]         INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL
)
```

I have this query that returns list of projects details with the number of use:

```
SELECT p.*, count(t.project_id) as length
FROM projects as p, tasks as t
WHERE p.id=t.project_id
GROUP BY p.code
ORDER BY length DESC;
```

but as I have found out it will return list smaller than projects if project id wasn't used (no task with given project id).

Is there a way to create a full list of projects in the same format to my current query and adding length but to include ALL projects and for those with no tasks length will have 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To also get projects without tasks, use a [left outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join).
The [ifnull](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) function converts any `NULL` to zero:

```sql
SELECT p.*, IFNULL(COUNT(t.project_id), 0) AS length
FROM projects AS p
LEFT JOIN tasks AS t ON p.id = t.project_id
GROUP BY p.code
ORDER BY length DESC
```

Comment: It works very well, would you be able to explain LEFT JOIN with your own words? Thanks.

Comment: :) nothing, but I like plain english explanation of the other developer. However whe I looked at this: _"The result of a left outer join (or simply left join) for tables A and B always contains all records of the "left" table (A)"_ - is pretty clear:)